# get PChar argument back from Delphi DLL in my Python script

Tags: python, delphi, dll, pchar

Let say that I've this function in a DLL

```
function test_3(sInput, sOutput : PChar; sSize : int64): Integer; stdcall;
var
  sTmp : string;
  fText : TextFile;
begin
  sTmp := '+++ ' + sInput + ' +++';
  StrPLCopy(sOutput, PChar(sTmp), sSize);
  Result := 69;
  AssignFile(fText, 'test.txt');
  Rewrite(fText);
  Writeln(fText, 'in: ' + sInput);
  Writeln(fText, 'out: '  + sOutput);
  CloseFile(fText);
end;
```

In my Delphi program, I call it like this

```
…
  Input := EdtIn.Text;
  OutputSize := Input.Length + 8;
  Output := AllocMem(OutputSize);
  RC := test_3(PChar(Input), Output, OutputSize);
  EdtOut.Text := Output;
  FreeMem(Output);
```

and it works quite well. Now I want to call the function from a Python script.

```
  import ctypes as ct
  ...
  myString = "test Delphi 10.3 DLL"
  outputsize = len(myString) + 8
  …
  test_3 = lib.test_3
  test_3.restype = ct.c_int
  test_3.argtypes = [ct.c_wchar_p, ct.c_wchar_p]
  sOutput = ct.create_string_buffer(outputsize)
  print("sOutput = " + sOutput.value)
```

and I get an error

> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: : wrong type

So my question is: what is the Python equivalent of AllocMem in Delphi.
I must precise that, of course all the code is for example and in "real life" I've no access to the Delphi code in DLL.

Comment: Try using `ct.c_char_p` as the argtype.

Comment: Is it possible to create dummy string of needed length and use it for the second argument?

Comment: Unicode Delphi, or ANSI Delphi? Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Delphi 2007 and older = ANSI, Delphi 2009 and newer = Unicode!

Comment: @Jeronimo How can you say that? You can't know whether the Delphi `PChar` is 8 bit or 16 bit.

Comment: @David Heffernan Because `ctypes.create_string_buffer` creates a `ctypes.c_char_Array`, which I thought was the direct cause for the "wrong type" error.

Comment: @Jeronimo But that would be the wrong fix if `PChar` was an alias for `PWideChar` (which it is for Delphi >= 2009). We can't answer the question until the asker provides the missing information requested in my comment above.

Comment: sorry, I've forgot to point out: Delphi 10.3 and Python 3.7

Comment: As you are using an Unicode Delphi version, your calculation for ``OutputSize`` (at least in the Delphi example, can't tell for Python) is wrong. AllocMem allocates memory in bytes, not in characters. So you need to double the value of ``OutputSize``, because a Unicode character is two bytes big.

Comment: and the input and output are ANSI string

Comment: "and the input and output are ANSI string". Not true. Since you are using Delphi 10.3 `PChar` is an alias for `PWideChar`, pointer to null terminated array of UTF-16 character elements. And yes, your memory allocation is broken. I would like to answer the question, but won't bring myself to do so until this is cleared up.

Comment: @David I have to ask my colleague who developed the "real life" DLL. I will see him tomorrow

Comment: @David, my colleague confirms me that the input and output are Unicode and not Ansi as I originally think.

Comment: @Delphi Coder, don't worry about the size of the output; the goal of the real DLL, developed by my colleague is to translate Edifact messages to Xml and JSon, so the output is set to 100 * size of the input.

Comment: I'll have a look at this later. But rest assured that none of us care in the least about your memory allocations. You however should care about your erroneous allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple and complete example demonstrating how to do this:

**Delphi library**

```pascal
library SO_60391682;

uses
  SysUtils;

function testStringOut(Input, Output: PChar; OutputLen: Int64): Integer; stdcall;
var
  tmp: string;
begin
  tmp := '+++ ' + Input + ' +++';
  StrPLCopy(Output, PChar(tmp), OutputLen - 1); 
  // -1 because of StrPLCopy's handling of null terminator
  Result := 0;
end;

exports
  testStringOut;

begin
end.
```

**Python program to call the Delphi library**

```py
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.WinDLL(r'SO_60391682.dll')
testStringOut = lib.testStringOut
testStringOut.restype = ctypes.c_int
testStringOut.argtypes = ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_int64

output = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(256)
res = testStringOut('foo', output, len(output))
print('res={}, output={}'.format(res, output.value))
```

Comment: Yesssss, you save me. I've missed the "create_unicode_buffer". Thank you very much.